# Unsure what is meant by "driving variables"

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out the intersection between two line segments. I am using the equation. I am using the following formula:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line

this works for lines, but it states the following for line segments:

> Note that the intersection point is for the infinitely long lines
>   defined by the points, rather than the line segments between the
>   points, and can produce an intersection point beyond the lengths of
>   the line segments. If (rather than solving for the point in a single
>   step), the solution in terms of first degree Bézier parameters is
>   first found, then this intermediate result can be checked for 0.0 ≤ t
>   ≤ 1.0 and 0.0 ≤ u ≤ 1.0 (**where t and u are the driving
>   variables)**.

What on earth is meant by "the driving variables"? I am in no way a mathematician, and am just trying to convert this formula into C# code. I do not understand what is meant by this. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

They mean this:

If you have two points: $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$, then each point on this segment $[A,B]$ (on the segment, not on the line $(A,B)$ as a whole), can be calculated by the formula: $C = (x(t), y(t)) = (x_1 + t.(x_2-x_1), y_1 + t.(y_2-y_1))$, where $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
So here $t$ is this driving variable.

In my native language we also call it independent or free variable, and we say that when $t$ runs through the interval $[0, 1]$, the point $C$ runs through the segment $[A,B]$.

Seems you want to program this. Just apply the formula from Wikipedia, then find the two t values (for the intersection point with respect to the two segments given). If these t values are both in the $[0,1]$ interval, then it means the two segments intersect in a point which is internal (to both segments).

Comment: This comment came as a suggested edit to the question: I am still a bit confused. how do I find t? I understand what is meant by this now so far as a "Driving variable", which is great; but in the context of this equation what would t be? Given two lines; say: L1([x=1, y=1], [x=1, y=10)]) and, L2([x=0, y=5], [x=10, y=5])... The intersection would be at [x=1, y=5], and as such t would be between 0 and 1. but, what on earth is t?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If I am not mistaken, it's 4/9 for the 1st segment and it's 1/10 for the 2nd segment. One can see it almost without writing any equations (just by making a drawing/sketch). Basically it's the proportion in which the intersecting point divides the two segments, that's what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I hope it helps the OP, too. (The situation seems to be this: The OP is an unregistered user and lost access to their account. They wanted clarification for the answer, and posted it as a new user as a suggested edit to the question. I rejected the edit and posted it here instead. I hope the OP sees your comment.)